# How to programmatically delete a work item in Rally?

Tags: rally

I'm customising cards by using a custom card renderer on a cardboard and would like to add a 'Remove' button on each card in order to do the same 'delete' functionality as provided in the Iteration Status page (i.e move the item to recycle bin).

By inspection, I can see on click the following event is fired when deleting stories from 'Iteration Status' page:

onclick="deleteAR({itemOid:'1234', name:'Item name', formattedID:'Item001', msg:'Are you sure?'}); return false;"

Edit: I'm using JDK 1.3

Comment: Are you using SDK 1.x or 2.x preview?

Comment: Unfortunately this functionality is unavailable in SDK 1.x.  It is quite trivial in the 2.x preview however.  Extending the cardboard has changed quite a bit during the preview but we will be releasing a stable 2.0p4 with an updated customized cardboard example that should be a good start for what you want...  I'll post a better code example next week...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to delete in SDK 1.x like so:

```
function delete(ref, callback, errorCallback) {
    var config = {
        url: ref,
        content: {},
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        handleAs:"json",
        preventCache: true,
        load: callback,
        error: errorCallback
    };

    if (rally.sdk.util.Context.isInsideRally()) {   
        dojo.xhrDelete(config);
    } else {
        config.callbackParamName = "jsonp";
        config.content._method = "DELETE";
        dojo.io.script.get(config);
    }
}

//delete an item
delete('https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.32/defect/12345.js',
    function(results) {
        //success
    },
    function(results) {
        //error
    }
);
```

We were going to expose this functionality via rally.sdk.data.io.httpDelete and rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource.delete but never fully tested and released it.